# SQL Server : single update multiple properties

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to optimize some if my SQL functions and wondered if this could be turned in more performant query.

```
DECLARE @SPAN INT;
SET @SPAN = 1;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;  
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

UPDATE UserSession 
SET PauseSpan = PauseSpan + @SPAN,
    PauseSpanTotal = PauseSpanTotal + @SPAN  
WHERE State & 8 = 8;

UPDATE UserSession 
SET Span = Span + @SPAN
WHERE State & 1 = 1;

UPDATE UserSession 
SET PendSpan = PendSpan + @SPAN,
    PendSpanTotal = PendSpan + @SPAN
WHERE State & 4 = 4 ;   

SELECT 
    UserSessionId AS Id, UserId, HostId, State, Span,
    BilledSpan, PendTime, PendSpan, EndTime, CreatedById, CreatedTime,
    Slot, PendSpanTotal, PauseSpan, PauseSpanTotal 
FROM 
    UserSession 
WHERE 
    State & 1 =1;

COMMIT;
```

What function has is an INT span value and what I am trying to do is update a set of different properties based on current entity state.

The function is called almost every second and records that needs to be updated might be ranged from one to thousands so since I am under serializable lock I want to make this as performant as possible.

Also at the end of the query I do a `SELECT` based on a parameter, the question is would it be possible to return only the records that was modified and would it be more performant?

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can return only the updated records by using a output clause : https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-output-clause-for-insert-and-delete-statements

Comment: The biggest win here would be to get rid of `State`, or at least have some additional computed columns. Bit flags suck in a database. If they're separate `BIT` columns, you can create filtered indexes on them, which makes looking them up tons more efficient. Alternatively, if this query can be expected to update just about every row, just in different ways, you can fuse the whole query into one by having `CASE` expressions for each affected column. This has a bigger impact if all the lookups are table scans (as they probably currently are) than when indexes can be used.

Comment: the bit flags should not be the problem here as the state is actually always equal to a specific value, for example it could be where State =7 or State =2 e.t.c.
Now i am not expert in SQL and from examples that i see i can only use CASE to update a single column ? Or am i mistaking ?

Comment: The problem (well, *a* problem, technically I don't know if it's an actual performance issue in your database since I don't know the row counts) is that `WHERE State & 1 = 1` cannot be satisfied except by a table scan, computing `State & 1` for every row. Your three updates are effectively all scanning the whole table, which means you have three table scans here, when at the very least you could just have one. With `CASE` you'd get something like `SET Span = CASE WHEN State & 1 = 1 THEN Span + @Span ELSE Span END` (but I'd look at optimizing the queries into index seeks first).

Comment: I am currently experimenting with around 350 records that have the State have 1 flag, i figured it is possible to do multiple SET for different columns but after trying converting the code to something like this UPDATE UserSession 
SET PauseSpan  = CASE 
WHEN State =1 then Span+ @SPAN ELSE Span
END
COMMIT;  
the performance is actually got worse from 20ms it went to 70ms with just this statement.

Comment: Of course, because that statement updates all rows, and the original one does not. (SQL Server does not "optimize away" an update of the form `SET X = X`.) It ought to be faster only if you replace all three statements with one update statement this way. But, again, you probably don't *want* to be updating all rows in the first place (assuming these statements don't cover all possible rows) in which case indexing the states makes more sense than trying to produce one glorious update statement.

Comment: ok makes sense with SET , so it seem that the current way would be more optimal and especially if extra indexing added ? As i said state can be queried without bit checks with something like State = 2 OR State = 9 etc, this should also be more performant right since SQL server wont need to do bit operations ?

Comment: Yes and no -- if there is an index on `State`, then that can be used when you have equality comparisons. But it might not actually end up being used, if the optimizer decides the index is not sufficiently selective (i.e. if you have about half the rows with `State = 2` and half where `State <> 2`, then a statement that does `WHERE State = 2` could still end up with a scan because the optimizer doesn't think just filtering half the rows is good enough). The index will also have some maintenance overhead if rows frequently change state. It's not necessarily a silver bullet, but worth trying.

Comment: Ok , one more observation. When i removed the BEGIN TRANSACTION statements and tried executing same query without wrapping it within a SERIALIZABLE TRANSACTION the time has increased, is there any logical explanation for this ?